# How do I use a dictionary to find the average of the grades in the list using a file?

Tags: file, dictionary, python-3.7

The file grades.txt contains random students' grades in a fictional course. Each line of the file is a student's name, followed by a space, followed by an integer grade. I want to write a program that reads in the data from the file, and then prints out each student's name and average score.

I have a general sense of what I want to do, and I’m working to make it more precise, but I am a bit confused. I know that I should read the file and use the dictionary to store the grades and average them, but I'm not sure how to use a file and a dictionary at the same time.

```py
inFile = open('grades.txt','r')
lines = inFile.read()

fix_list = lines.replace('\n',' ') #Replace '\n' with spaces before getting rid of them.
new_list = fix_list.split(' ') #List without spaces or '\n'
length_list = len(new_list) - 1 
print(new_list)
```

Here is what is in the grades.txt file specifically:

```
Cleese 80
Gilliam 78
Jones 69
Jones 90
Cleese 90
Chapman 90
Chapman 100
Palin 80
Gilliam 82
Cleese 85
Gilliam 80
Gilliam 75
Idle 91
Jones 90
Palin 90
Cleese 88
```

This is what my code is supposed to spit out (not in a new file, but just to print):

```
Gilliam 78.75
Jones 83.0
Cleese 85.75
Chapman 95.0
Idle 91.0
Palin 85.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are doing in your code snippet.

What you want to do is:

- Instantiate a dictionary
- Use readlines() instead of read() on the file so that you get the lines in a list
- For each line, split it and store the grade in the dictionary such that the name is the key, and the value is all the grades in a list.
- Loop over the dictionary and print the name and average. For average you can do sum(list)/len(list)